# Selenium returns NoSuchElementException Error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I`m a newbie to python.
Recently I got interested in Web Crawling.

Today I got stuck in **NoSuchElementException**

This is the webpage that i want to scrape.

[image]

When I click the username that i erased, it returns box like this.

[image]

Though I used the xpath that i copied from Chrome developer tool,
it returns me **NoSuchElementException**:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-area"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

HTML is like this

```
<a href="#" class="m-tcol-c" onclick="ui(event, 'royaltina',3,'이주연마인','25868806','me', 'false', 'true', 'schoolch', 'false', '5'); return false;">이주연마인</a>
```

My code is just like this,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"main-area\"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
```

I checked there is this xpath, but when I get it into .find_element_by_xpath() method it returns Error.

I do really share the webpage, but it needs to log-in to get there,
So i cannot share the webpage.

Could you guess what might cause this problem?

I checked time is not the problem.
I checked iframe is not the problem.

Thank you in advance
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element with text as **이주연마인** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "이주연마인")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.m-tcol-c[onclick*='royaltina']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='m-tcol-c' and contains(@onclick, 'royaltina')][text()='이주연마인']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)